# Customize only getter but not setter of a property in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, properties, setter, getter

Read this in apple docs

**If you implement both a getter and a setter for a readwrite property, or a getter for a readonly property, the compiler will assume that you are taking control over the property implementation and won’t synthesize an instance variable automatically.**

My property variable is

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *notif;
```

When I override getter and setter manually then I am not able to access the variable using _notif, as expected. Compile time error is thrown upon using _notif.

Next, I override only getter (not setter) in my class as

```
@property (weak, nonatomic, getter=getMeNotif) IBOutlet UILabel *notif;
```

I tried 2 things to access the value of the given variable:
First,

```
[self notif].text = @"testing";
NSLog(@"%@",[self getMeNotif]);
```

Second,

```
_notif.text = @"testing";
NSLog(@"%@",[self getMeNotif]);
```

In both the cases, I get null on the console.
Am I using getter in a wrong way?

Comment: Overriding a setter and/or getter and declaring a different name for the setter/getter are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The first idea...

```
@property (weak, nonatomic, getter=getMeNotif) IBOutlet UILabel *notif;

// ...
[self notif].text = @"testing";
```

won't compile because it uses a getter, `notif`, that disagrees with the declared getter, `getMeNotif`.

The second idea using the same property declaration...

```
_notif.text = @"testing";
NSLog(@"%@",[self getMeNotif]);
```

...should work, but only if: (a) **if** you've specified a function for your custom getter, it must return the instance variable...

```
- (UILabel *)getMeNotif {
    // anything you want here
    // but the function must end like this:
    return _notif;
}
```

and (b) the outlet is properly setup in IB so that _notif is non-null.  To make certain your test works -- as opposed to an outlet problem -- try this:

```
_notif = [[UILabel alloc] init];
_notif.text = @"testing";
NSLog(@"%@",[self getMeNotif]);
```